# Starting the back end of an app

Tags: android, ios, web, backend

Can someone simply point me in the right direction - maybe a few links - so that I can start learning to construct the back-end for an app. Lets say I want to create an app that allows users to sign in with their respective username and post status to a public feed. What languages, tutorials, etc should I be following. I have done some of my own research but I was hoping someone could save me the headache. Anything appreciated! Whether you know resources to help with web back ends or ios or android.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Stack Overflow is not a place to allocate work onto others. You must present a specific, answerable problem. Your question shows no effort put into it so what makes others motivated to answer it for nothing in return? Do some more research and put some work in. I personally learned to code on http://teamtreehouse.com/ which is a great resource but there are many others out there. Good Luck!

Comment: https://developer.android.com/training/index.html, as provided by a 2 second google search.

Comment: i know html and css and javascript and java and jquery and some of angularjs. I just need help I have searched forever and have not found the right resources to help me learning backend dev as far as setting of a serve and database.

Comment: how is this a bad question?

Comment: The answers are opinion based and there is no 'correct' answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can start with this for setting up registration/login system through server:

http://www.androidhive.info/2012/01/android-login-and-registration-with-php-mysql-and-sqlite/